# Validity of equating line integral with emf

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

imagine trivial induction scenario of static loop in variable magnetic field.

So the emf is the total work per unit charge that a charge in a e.g wire will gain as a result of moving through a path in a vector field.

I am completely fine with the idea that IF a charge were to be forced to move in a certain path then the total work attained to charge by the vector field E is given by:

Closed Line Integral of E . Dl

However lets imagine that in a wire there is empty space and a SINGLE free electron, now the line integral is e.g anti clockwise positive, so IF the electron  WERE to move in this path the E field would do work on it.

Now the issue I have is thay just because if something were to move in that path and would 'gain ' work, that doesnt neccesserily mean that it WILL move in that path.

E.g say for instance there are 6 "nodes" with E vector values in a certain path, 4 point anti clockwise and 2 point clockwise, this will result in a line integral of "4 work elements"  ( assuming they are parrallel to dr).

So lets say the electron is in the positon such that it crosses 2 vector arrows that Do work, then immedietly after crosses 2 vector arrows that do NEGATIVE work, in this scenario the electron ,even though in the wire, will NOT gain "4 work elements" as it will never complete the full path and will osscillate between the opposite arrows.

So what is the validity of saying that the emf is E.dl for induction if not all electrons (in this specific scenario) complete the full path.

From a previous post someone said that as a result of the moving electrons the E field will always be in the direction of movement, however at the instant induction takes place the electrons dont move.

The issue may be that i have no idea what im talking about or it could be that im considering ONE electron and not the group as a whole.